# How to compare hex values using C?

Tags: c, hex

I am working with hex values. Until now I know how to print hex values and also precision thing. Now I want to compare the hex values. For example I am reading data from a file into a char buffer. Now I want to compare the hex value of data in the buffer. Is there anything like this?

```
if  hex(buffer[i]) > 0X3F  
then
//do somthing
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're nearly there:

```
if (buffer[i] > 0x3f)
{
    // do something
}
```

Note that there is no need to "convert" anything to hex - you can just compare character or integer values directly, since a hex constant such as 0x3f is just another way of representing an integer value. 0x3f == 63 (decimal) == ASCII '?'.

Comment: ok sir thanks alot . although my buffer contain character values it can be compared with hex?

Comment: Yes - a char is really just one kind of integer in C and related languages - anything you can do with an int you can also do with a char.

Answer (score 7):

Numbers in the computer are all 0s and 1s. Looking at them in base 10, or base 16 (hex) , or as a character (such as 'a') doesn't change the number.

So, to compare with hex, you don't need to do anything.

For example, if you have

```
int a = 71;
```

Then the following two statements are equivalent:

```
if (a == 71)
```

and

```
if (a == 0x47)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can:

```
 if  (buffer[i] > 0x3F)
```

(note the lowercase x). **Edit** it turns out `0X3F` should work just as well, but I am tempted to say it is not what C programmers usually write).

Comment: ok sir thanks alot . although my buffer contain character values it can be compared with hex?

Comment: hex is only a _representation_. The computer only _stores_ numbers and you _interpret_ them as byte/char/float/string and the way you type them in code or print them to screen is a _text representation_

Comment: @another.anon.coward: apparently not. I'm just not used to seeing it uppercased. (_There is a difference when using printf (uppercase leters A-F) - but that's unrelated here_)

Comment: @sehe: True about `printf`. Also true that generally `X` is not used , but just so that OP knows that both work, in case `X` is seen somewhere instead of `x` :)

Answer (score 2):

When comparing char to hex you must be careful:

[Using the == operator to compare a char to 0x80 always results in false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844622/using-the-operator-to-compare-a-char-to-0x80-always-results-in-false)

I would recommend this syntax introduced in C99 to be sure

```
if (buffer[i] > '\x3f')
{
    // do something
}
```

It tells the compiler that the 0x3f is a char rather than an int (type-safety), otherwise it is likely you will see issue with this comparison.

In fact clang compiler will warn you about this:

comparison of constant 128 with expression of type 'char' is always false [-Werror,-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]

Answer (score 0):

Hex values are nothing new data types its just another numberical methods like

int a = 10;

**in Hex printing**

```
printf("a in hex value %x ",a);
```

output is

```
a in hex value A
```

in if loop

```
if(a == 0xa)
    do something
```

**in decimal**

```
printf("a in decimal value %d ",a);
```

output is

```
a in hex value 10
```

in if loop

```
if(a == 10)
    do something
```